# How do I open a folder in Sublime Text 2 and have the inner directory show up on the side, like in Brackets?

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have tried `Add Folder to a Project` but no sidebar shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

`View` - `Side Bar` - `Show Side Bar`